# How do I call 2 api in one class so that both work? (React)

Tags: reactjs, ajax, api, rxjs, frontend

I want to call api twice in one class but when I call another the first one no longer works. What should I do?

This is the code ---> P.S This is just a request code. I do not write rendering code

```
export class  Ajax1 extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            info:[],
            info2:[]
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        const url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
        const res=await fetch(url)
        const data= await res.json()
        this.setState({info:data})
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        const url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
        const res=await fetch(url)
        const data= await res.json()
        this.setState({info2:data})
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have more than one `componentDidMount` function in the same class:

```
async componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchInfo();
    this.fetchInfo2()
}

async fetchInfo(){
    const url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
    const res=await fetch(url)
    const data= await res.json()
    this.setState({info:data})
}

async fetchInfo2(){
    const url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    const res=await fetch(url)
    const data= await res.json()
    this.setState({info2:data})
}
```

Comment: To follow up on this, if you want to only update the state once, when both API calls have finished, you could use Promise.whenAll() in the componentDidMount function to only set the state when both promises have completed.

Comment: Yes,  you are right, I will update my answer, thanks

Comment: Also I recommend you to use Promise.all.

Comment: Oh yea sorry, I got the name mixed up with C#'s Task.WhenAll.